# How to restore a file that has been changed in node_modules?

Tags: node.js

I changed a file in node_modules and can get back to default state. Then I delete this file. Are there any npm command that I can use to load this file? I used npm install, audit. Didn't help, if it was supposed to help at all.

Comment: I'm a little confused. so you changed the file in `node_modules`, and then you were able to get it back to default state? What is the required task at hand here? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I change file in one of the module in node_modules. I forget how it was look before my changes. I need kind of patch module. In my case its Puppeteer.

Comment: okay yes, it seems like someone gave the correct answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try deleting the node_modules folder and running.

```
npm install
```

To reinstall all the packages. This will reinstall all module codes and solve your code conflicts and changes. If you need to keep any other changes, You can copy those modules folders and replace them after you reinstall the node modules.
And if you are a beginner, You can get a copy of the entire project folder and try using that to avoid any mistakes.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But actually I wonder there will be way to do it with a command kind of like 'npm patch <package-name>'.

Comment: The easiest way is to reinstall the modules. Because there can be accidentally edited files. But you can follow the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands) for other methods.